Graphviz not calculating exporting image correct inside docker container
I'm trying to render a graph using graphviz library.
I have an application running on a docker container. Whenever I run the command dot -Tsvg -Gsize=10,10\! -Gscale=1 -Eminlen=1 graph.dot -o output.svg within the container, the SVG generated has completely wrong coordinates attached to each node, while I run the same command in my local machine (macOS) I get a functional SVG.
My docker image is using php:8.1-fpm-alpine3.20 as a base image with the following Dockerfile:
# setup timezones properly
FROM alpine:3.17.0 AS timezone

RUN apk add tzdata

FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine3.20 as prod

ARG HOST_USER_ID
ARG HOST_GROUP_ID
ARG TIMEZONE

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ARG DEV_DEPS="libzip-dev libxml2-dev"

RUN echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
    echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
    echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
    apk update

COPY --from=timezone /usr/share/zoneinfo/${TIMEZONE} /etc/localtime

RUN set -xe && \
    echo "${TIMEZONE}" > /etc/timezone && \
    apk add --no-cache --update zlib libzip git openssh-client pcre-dev gmp-dev postgresql-dev libpq && \
    apk add --no-cache --update --virtual .phpize-deps ${PHPIZE_DEPS} && \
    apk add --no-cache --update --virtual .dev-deps ${DEV_DEPS} && \
    apk add ttf-dejavu && \
    apk add --no-cache --update graphviz>=11.0.0-r0 --repository="https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" && \
    # create app user
    addgroup -S -g ${HOST_GROUP_ID} app && \
    adduser -S -s /bin/sh -DS -u ${HOST_USER_ID} -G app app  && \
    # download and install composer
    php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && \
    php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer --2 && \
    php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" && \
    # update pecl extensions
    pecl channel-update pecl.php.net && \
    # install core extensions
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql pgsql zip xml opcache pcntl gmp sockets && \
    # cleanup
    apk del --purge .phpize-deps .dev-deps && \
    rm -rf /tmp/* && \
    rm -rf /usr/share/php8 && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

FROM prod as dev

RUN set -xe && \
    apk add --no-cache --update zlib libzip git openssh-client pcre-dev linux-headers && \
    apk add --no-cache --update --virtual .phpize-deps ${PHPIZE_DEPS} && \
    apk add --no-cache --update --virtual .dev-deps ${DEV_DEPS} && \
    # install extension via pecl
    pecl install xdebug && \
    # enable extensions installed via pecl
    docker-php-ext-enable xdebug && \
    # cleanup
    apk del --purge .phpize-deps .dev-deps && \
    rm -rf /tmp/* && \
    rm -rf /usr/share/php8 && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

The graph.dot I'm feeding to the dot command is:
digraph Workflow {
  rankdir=TB;

  ValidateDescription [ label=ValidateDescription, style=filled, fillcolor=green, color=black ];
  SendEmail [ label=SendEmail, style=filled, fillcolor=red ];
  end [ label=end, style=filled, fillcolor=red ];
  ValidateDescription -> SendEmail [ label=pass, color=darkgreen ];
  ValidateDescription -> end [ label=fail, color=red ];
  SendEmail -> end [ label=success, color=darkgreen ];
  SendEmail -> end [ label=fail, color=red ];
} /* /digraph Workflow */


The weird thing is: if I only leave two nodes in my dot, it works wonderfuly inside Docker and my local machine.
digraph Workflow {
  rankdir=TB;

  ValidateDescription [ label=ValidateDescription, style=filled, fillcolor=green, color=black ];
  SendEmail [ label=SendEmail, style=filled, fillcolor=red ];
} /* /digraph Workflow */

What is causing this issue? How can I debug this in order to fix be able to generate appropriate SVG output?

Possibly Alpine / Docker  font problems.  see https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues/2440
what does fc-list produce?
